# Android GET Http request from API

Tags: android, get, httprequest

Hello I'm trying to receive some data from this API

[http://docs.sygictravelapi.com/1.1/](http://%20http://docs.sygictravelapi.com/1.1/)

The problem is that I'm getting on failure all the time with these exceptions:

> Failure cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpResponseException:
>   Unauthorized Status Code:    401

I think the problem is that I don't send a Header!

My code is:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

params.put("location", locationParameter);
params.put("x-api-key", API_KEY);



AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get(API_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int status, Header[] headers, JSONObject response)
        {

            Log.d("App", "JSON:   " + response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int status, Header[] headers, Throwable ex, JSONObject response)
        {
            Log.e("Dimos", "Failure " + ex.toString());
            Log.d("Dimos", "Status Code:    " + status);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivityController.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to use AsyncHttpClient? Retrofit is the most common used library to make http requests and it will be very easy to send a header intercepting the OkHttp: https://square.github.io/retrofit/ https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Comment: I'm asuming you contacted them to get a valid x-api-key?

Comment: @jonathanrz Im new in java code and I havent heard about retrofit library until now! I will check it thanks.

Comment: @DaanSeuntjens i made registration and they sent me a key. I think that is ok.

Comment: I would suggest testing it in postman to test if you can get a valid response back. In java I used this code to have basic authentication:                         
     String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(("your_username" + ":" + "your_key").getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded); But I don't know how it would work with only a key